# Printar conteudos de um array em uma tag com id, a partir de uma função que é chamada com um onclick

Tags: javascript, html5

Oiii, eu estou tentando fazer uma função que é chamada a partir de um onclick e nela pegar os valores de tags, após precionar o botão e transformar os dados em colunas de um array, eu gostaria de printar esse array em uma pagina com tags com id especifico.

O meu problema é que não aparece nada que eu tento printar com o .innerHTML

```
let nome_receita
let ingredientes
let preparo
function enviar(){
    nome_receita = document.getElementById('nome_receita').value;
    ingredientes = document.getElementById('ingredientes').value;
    preparo = document.getElementById('preparo').value;

    if (nome_receita === '' || ingredientes === '' || preparo === ''){
        alert('preencher todos os campos');
    }else{
        document.getElementById('nome_receita').value = '';
        document.getElementById('ingredientes').value = '';
        document.getElementById('preparo').value = '';

        alert('Obrigado por sua contribuição! <3');

        let receita = Array()

        receita.push(nome_receita);
        receita.push(ingredientes);
        receita.push(preparo);
        let v1 = receita[0];
        let v2 = receita[1];**texto em negrito**
        let v3 = receita[2];
        console.log(receita);

        document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = v1;
        document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = v2;
        document.getElementById('c').innerHTML = v3;
        
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rafael, o innerHTML geralmente é usado para executar trechos de código do próprio HTML.

Exemplo:

```
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = '<b>Negrito</b>';
```

O ideal nesses casos é utilizar o innerText ao invés do innerHTML. Dessa forma:

```
document.getElementById('a').innerText = v1;
```

Faça esse teste. Como sou iniciante no fórum, não consigo comentar sua pergunta ainda, mas tenho uma dúvida, quando você executa essa linha:

```
console.log(receita);
```

O array está preenchido corretamente?

Answer (score -2):

Ta faltando o operador `new`:

```
let receita = Array()
```

o certo:

```
let receita = new Array();
```

Comment: Não deu certo :c